# Improperly functioning Septic system

Tags: plumbing

What is the proper pipe to use in a raised septic bed with a capacity of 3100 liters daily and approximately 45ft long x 16 ft. wide. The builder has used 4 o clock x 6 o clock x 8 o clock half inch perforated,3 inch sewer pipe. I have a serious problem that most of the water is exiting the first 25 feet of the bed and only approximately 5 percent is making it to the far end of the bed. I am getting breakout in the ditch 25 feet away. This was a new home build 20 months ago and this has been an ongoing dispute as to what the problem is. I say they have used the wrong pipe. There are no brakes in the system. Any opinion would be appreciated.

Don

Comment: Where are you located?  That's a small mound and I suspect it's not adequate.  In my area, the local health department would be my resource.  Here is a good guide from Maryland, USA that may help you understand your system capacity https://mde.state.md.us/programs/Water/BayRestorationFund/OnsiteDisposalSystems/Documents/Onsite%20Systems/Sand%20Mound%20Manual.pdf and this is a less-comprehensive resource with some lateral pipe info (you haven't provided enough data but your laterals may be okay -- if you had more field area) https://www.extension.purdue.edu/extmedia/id/id-163.html

Answer (score 0):

My guess as to the most likely problem is improper slope of the line, which should be whatever the septic design calls for (mine calls for dead level on the distribution lines, but mine is also not a mound system.)

Pipe size and holes should also be as per design - and I'm skeptical of the 6 o'clock holes being correct. Your septic design should be both on-file with the public health department or whoever oversees septic installations/permits in your area, and in your homeowner documentation of your new-built home.

If you don't have a copy of the septic design documents, you should be able to request a copy (probably for a fee) from the permitting authority. You should also be able to get the inspection report from when it was signed off by their inspector.

If the system is built as designed and permitted, then you have an issue with the system designer; if it's not built as designed and permitted, you have an issue with the builder.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of perf pipe and a drainfield is that the pipe has holes on half of the pipe and it’s installed perfectly level with the holes on the top half.

Then, when the liquid flows down the pipe, it fills the entire pipe up until it “overflows” out the holes. That way, the entire septic field gets used ALL THE TIME and very little is deposited in any one location.

Btw, you need an active septic tank so the solids have time to “breakdown” to just liquids so solids don’t plug the holes in the pipe or the drainfield.